# populating zend form's fieldsets with objects within object

Tags: php, data-binding, zend-framework2

I am using PHP Zendframework to build forms. I have service object that i need want to use to populate my ServiceEditForm.php. But in this service form i have Object of "Billing", "Subscription" and array of object "Commands". Below is my implementation of Service class.

```
 class Service{
public $service_id;
public $ServiceName;
public $TelecomOperator;
public $SubMethod;
public $Provider;
public $active;



public $billingType;
public $subscriptionPlan;
public $commands;

function exchangeArray(array $data);}
```

I want to bind the object of Service class to my Edit form which used subscription, billing and commands related data as fieldsets. I am able to populate service values in form using bind but not other objects. here is my form implementation

```
     class ServiceEditForm extends Form{

public function __construct($name = null)
{
    parent::__construct('Edit Service');
    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
    $this->setAttribute('enctype','multipart/form-data');

    //here i have other fields that belongs to service object

    $this->add( array(
        'name' => 'billingType',
        'type' => 'Services\Form\BillingTypeFieldset',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Billing Type',
        ),
    ));


    $this->add( array(
        'name' => 'subscriptionPlan',
        'type' => 'Services\Form\SubscriptionPlanFieldset',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Subscription Plan',
        ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
         'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
         'name' => 'commands',
         'options' => array(
             'label' => 'commands',
             'count' => 2,
             'should_create_template' => true,
             'allow_add' => true,
             'target_element' => array(
                 'type' => 'Services\Form\CommandFieldset',
             ),
         ),
     ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'submit',
            'value' => 'Save'
        ),
    )); 
}
```

}

As I said I am not able to populate fieldsets with bind within form with this implementation. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: i am able to researched a bit and able to resolve (but not fully understand the concept behind). I replace the hydrator ClassMethods with ArraySerializable and make a turnaround for me.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have already answer the question after looking up for possible solutions but Hydrator Implementations given in this link is also useful in explaining the very basics that one should read before using it. My bad i didn't went for full-throttled study before implementing fieldsets.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.html

This url explain possible implementation of hydrators that can deliver you very easy binding solution for your class.